# Replicar query SQL avg over() en DAX Power BI

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, dax

Esperando que estén todos bien, necesito de su gran ayuda, estoy replicando unas querys de SQL a DAX en power bi, pero no logro hacer lo siguiente, la **funcion AVG()over()**, la cual entrega el promedio final redondeado y lo replica por cada fila, agrupando.

La query es la siguiente:

```
declare @Test table (fecha int,intk int,categoria int)
insert into @Test
select 1,30,222
union
select 2,20,222
union
select 3,20,222
union
select 1,30,333
union
select 2,20,333
union
select 3,20,333

  select Fecha, avg(Fecha) over () as Var1,
               intk, avg(intk) over () as Var2
        from @Test
        group by categoria,Fecha,intk
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda-